# empty? does not stop Racket from running expression

Tags: racket, conditional-statements, empty-list

I'm trying to have function get a number out of a structure that is inside a list. When the list is empty, the function should output +inf.0.

However, when I input an empty list like this: (function (list empty)), the +inf.0 part is ignored and the else expression is executed anyway leading to the error that struct-xyz gets an empty list or that first doesn't allow empty lists. What am I doing wrong?

```
(define (function datalist)) 
(cond 
 [(empty? datalist) +inf.0]
 [else(struct-xyz (first datalist))]))
```

This is all in the Beginning Student Teaching Language.

Comment: I assume you've got a typo in your definition and you meant `(define (function datalist) ...)`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `(function empty)`, not  `(function (list empty))`. `(function (list empty))` is calling your function on a list that is *not* empty, it contains one element (another list, which is empty).